# If $\mu(A\triangle B)=0$ then $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mu$ is finite measure and $\mu(A\triangle B)=0$.

Show that $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$

My work:

$\mu(A\triangle B)=0=\mu(A|B)+\mu(B|A)=(\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B))+(\mu(B)-\mu(B\cap A))$

So $\mu(A)=-\mu(B)+2\mu(B\cap A)$

How is $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mu$ is a measure, it must be non-negative. Now, $\mu(A\backslash B)+\mu(B\backslash A)=0$. So, we must have $\mu(A\backslash B)=\mu(B\backslash A)=0$.

The rest is just our old set theory.

Comment: Doesnt $\mu(A\backslash B)+\mu(B\backslash A)=0\implies \mu(A\backslash B)=-\mu(B\backslash A)$?

Comment: @gbd Sum of two non-negative values is being $0$. So?

Comment: @VIVID exactly. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The measure $\mu$ does not have to be finite. Note $A \Delta B = \{x : \chi_A(x) \neq \chi_B(x)\}$. Thus $\mu(A \Delta B) = 0$ if and only if $\chi_A = \chi_B$ a.e. If $\chi_A = \chi_B$ a.e., then $\mu(A) = \int \chi_A = \int \chi_B = \mu(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awnser of Sayan Dutta above + the following below
\begin{align*}
\mu(A)=\mu((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c))
&=\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(A\cap B^c)\\
&=\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(A\setminus B)\\
&=\mu(A\cap B),
\end{align*}
because $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$. Similary for $B$.

Is a little late, but I'm studing this now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).